# Ruby Exceptions Initialize Error

Tags: ruby

I have to create a program where I have to ask the user for their first and last name on a single line. If the user puts only their first OR last name, it will be rejected through the exception. I keep getting an error at the end (below).

```
 class MyNewException < Exception
      attr_accessor :first, :last
      def initialize (first, last)
        @first = first
        @last = last
      end
    end

print "Enter your first and last name:"

begin

first, last = gets.chomp.split

print "Hello," + first + " " + last + "!"

if last.size == 0
  raise MyNewException, "Sorry, I didn't catch that! Try again:"
end
rescue MyNewException
  puts "Sorry, I didn't catch that. Try again:"
  retry
end
```

Keep getting an error:

```
testing.rb:15:in `+': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

Comment: add a default value `def initialize(first = nil, last = nil)`

Comment: Two errors here: one is the lack of comma (`raise MyNewException, "Sorry, I didn't quite catch that! Try again:"`) or explicit construction of an exception(`raise MyNewException.new("Sorry, I didn't quite catch that! Try again:")`); the other is the wrong constructor on your exception. Why does your exception have a name? :) Exceptions typically only have a message in their default constructor. If you really want to make a custom exception with a name, you'd raise it with `raise MyNewException.new('John', 'Doe')`.

Comment: @NewbeeDev Thanks that worked! Also, Do I create a loop within the rescue in order to re-ask the user for the full name?

Comment: @SarahKim should your first name and last name seperated? since they are in different variables. I think you should have 2 user inputs. for the first name and last name

Answer (score 2):

The [raise() docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) are faulty.  You can do this:

```
puts "Enter your first and last name:"
name = gets.chomp

class MyNewException < Exception

  def initialize(str)
    super(str)  #pass the value for the message property to the parent class
  end

end

begin
  raise MyNewException, "Sorry, I didn't quite catch that! Try again:"
rescue MyNewException => e
  puts e.message
end

--output:--
Enter your first and last name:
Sarah Kim
Sorry, I didn't quite catch that! Try again:
```

Or:

```
puts "Enter your first and last name:"
name = gets.chomp

class MyNewException < Exception

  attr_accessor :first, :last

  def initialize(user_name, exception_message)
    @first, @last = user_name.split
    super exception_message
  end

end

begin
  raise MyNewException.new(name, "I didn't quite catch that! Try again:")
rescue MyNewException => e
  puts e.message
  puts e.first
  puts e.last
end

--output:--
Enter your first and last name:
Sarah Kim
I didn't quite catch that! Try again:
Sarah
Kim
```

Here's how to write an infinite loop to get user input:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :first, :last

  def initialize(first, last)
    @first = first.capitalize
    @last = last.capitalize
  end
end

while true
  puts "Enter your first and last name:"
  first, last = gets.chomp.split
  #Show what you got:
  p first
  p last

  if first and last  
  #If no names were entered, both first and last will be nil.
  #If one name was entered, first will evaluate to true and last will be nil.
  #If two names were entered, first and last will evaluate to true.
  #If two or more names were entered, first and last will evaluate to true.
    user = Person.new first, last
    break  #jump to the line immediately after the infinite loop
  end

  puts "Sorry, you must enter both a first and a last name.  Try again"
end

puts "Thanks #{user.first} #{user.last}!"
```

Comment: Thanks for the two advices!!! Now I'm confused where to put the loop for re-asking to try again for a new input of the name... Do I make a class above again for the loops? @7stud

Comment: No, the class should go at the very top--outside the loop.  Typically, when you want to ask someone for input, you create an infinite loop that keeps asking for the input over and over, then you break out of the loop if the input is correct, which will prevent the question from being asked again.  You don't need an Exception to do that.

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to mix an Exception object and a Person object.  It's not clear why you are doing that, i.e. why should an Exception object be used to store user input?

Comment: I ended up just adding name = String(gets.chomp) for the 2nd line and e.message = String(gets.chomp) to repeat the question afterwards but now Im stuck trying to add in the greeting once it allows accepting the names... Idk I'm totally new to ruby/coding in general so everything is taking me some time @7stud

Comment: `chomp()` returns a String, so calling `String()` does nothing useful.  See the bottom of my answer for an infinite loop that gets user input.  As a beginner, I suggest you forget about Exceptions for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Create a loop that do your trial and error.
as for my answer I choose while loop

```
i = 0
while i < 1 do

    if condition == true
        # display your greetings then increment loop to  end
        i += 1
    else
        # display error message
    end

end
```

So your code would be like this

```
class MyNewException < Exception

  attr_accessor :first, :last, :valid

  def initialize(first, last)
    @first = first
    @last = last
    @valid = true
    if first.empty? || last.empty? then
        @valid = false
    end
  end

end

i = 0

while i < 1 do

    print "Enter your first name: "
    firstname = gets.chomp
    print "Enter your last name: "
    lastname = gets.chomp

    name = MyNewException.new(firstname, lastname)

    if name.valid then
        puts "Greetings " << name.first << " " << name.last
        i += 1
    else
        puts "I didn't quite catch that! Try again:"
    end

end
```

[image]

Comment: No idea why someone down voted this lol!!!! You are totally awesome! The main reason that I am struggling is that the output for this program should be first and last name given at the same time. So the user should be able to enter their full name in the beginning in a whole instead of "Enter your first name, Enter your last name"

Comment: @SarahKim perhaps marking it answer and upvote makes me satisfy after my hard work in this code :)